# Trying to Add Task Due Date on Add Task button

Tags: button, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I am trying to add the Due Date(Activity Date) field to the button/action layout when a user clicks the Add button to add a Task on the Account page. I have looked all over where I thought it would be in quick action layouts and I cannot find it. Does anyone out there know if this is possible to add?

Below are pictures of where the Add button to create a new Task is on our Account page layout, as well as where I would like to add the Due Date(Activity Date) field. Any help is sincerely appreciated. Thank you so much!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is actually done under Global Actions, then in New Task:

[image]